# Windows Phone 8 GeoCoordinateWatcher vs Geolocator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, location

Windows Phone 8 has the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` which is present in Windows Phone 7, but it also has [`Geolocator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator), both of which perform the same function, i.e. allow you to 'watch' for changes in geolocation. I can't find any information about whether `GeoCoordinateWatcher` is deprecated, whether `Geolocator` should now be used - or the differences between the two.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple - if you don't need or plan version for WP7, only for WP8, then use the Geolocator - it is better configurable than GeoCoordinateWatcher.
Or, there is another solution that I have used in my app, use Dependency Injection and implement common interface for your geolocation service, that will be implemented using Geolocator in WP8 version and using GeoCoordinateWatcher in WP7.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - In what ways is it better than GeoCoordinateWatcher? If I go to the hassle of dependency injection of this service - I want to know what the benefits are!

Comment: The first thing that I remember - you can set the ReportInterval property on Geolocator, how frequently to receive location updates.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, Geolocator can be used in the background while GeoCoordinateWatcher cannot.

I wrote about it when the WP8 SDK leaked. My post is below if you want to take a look but I believe the MSDN documentation should cover it somewhere as well.

http://www.adambenoit.com/development/continuous-location-tracking-windows-phone-8-part-2-background/

Hope this additional info is useful.

Comment: I use GeoCoordinateWatcher in my WP7 app in background task and it works fine. I just had to use synchronization primitives to wait for the GeoCoordinateWatcher to initialize.

Comment: I honestly never considered that approach. Good to know. Feel free to down-vote my answer, I wont mind :)

Comment: I also got that impression, but looks like GeoCoordinateWatcher can be used for background tracking the same way as Geolocator can.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/A_Windows_Phone_8_Run_Tracking_App_in_100_Lines_of_Code!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/jj945729

I think the confusion initially was caused by this article, although there is no explicit notion of that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not just they have the same function, but Geolocator is really fast, i've made some testing, and while a good old GeoCoordinateWatcher gets your position in about 3 seconds in a rough area, GeoLocator takes about 0.3 seconds to locate you. So win for the GeoLocator.

By the way, I think that by "Geolocator can run in the background", they refer to use it like they use in this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx

That is, without the limitations of a Background Agent. I would recommend we start adopting GeoLocator, unles off course, you're targetting both WP 7.8 and WP8